# Display ellipsis when using line breaks "\n" in UILabel - Swift Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel, ellipsis

I want to display ellipsis (...) at the end of the sentence, and this is my sample string data :

`"Baked Mac & Cheese \n Fries \n Soda etc."` .

I display it like this:

- Baked Mac & Cheese
- Fries
- Soda

I want to display ellipsis on the right part of every words if the next string data are not visible on the UILabel. I want to display like this:

- Baked Mac & Cheese
- Fries...

The ellipsis is displayed because not all the string data is displayed. I tried using `label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail` but the ellipsis is not shown, i think because the word "Fries" does not touched the edge of the UILabel, or it maybe because of `\n` next to it?

Comment: Are you assign static height and width to label? What about bullet? Already you added?

Comment: I gave height as 41 and  .byTruncatingTail, numberOflines 2, I am getting output, Baked Mac & Cheese \n Fries...

Comment: @JD. Height and width of the label is not static. It can be expanded, because, it will be based on the collection view above it that has dynamic data. So if the collection view has few data, then the label should be longer, but if collection view has more data, label should be smaller.